# Вопрос по NetBeens

Tags: ide, netbeans, visual-studio

Решил попробовать Java. Раньше программировал на Visual Studio. Есть ли подобное решение для Java? Я слышал что таковым является NetBeens. Так ли это? Под словом *подобное* я имел ввиду Windows Form и подобные плюшки visual studio хD.

Answer (score 1):

[Сравнение IDE](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сравнение_IDE#Java).
`NetBeans` - бесплатная `IDE`, [Загрузка среды NetBeans 7.1](http://netbeans.org/downloads/). Прост в установке и почти или вообще не требует настройки, для новичка в самый раз. Работа в середе интуитивно понятна, русифицирована. Расширение/ добавление плагинов делается достаточно просто и удобно. Имеется много русской литературы. На [русском сайте](http://netbeans.org/index_ru.html) есть хорошая документация (при переходах по страницам язык автоматически не меняется, нужно сменить в ручную).
`Eclipse` - тоже бесплатная, [Eclipse Indigo (3.7.1)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). Сложнее в настройке. Богатый набор всевозможных плагинов.
`IDEA` - очень хорошая среда, не бесплатная.

Answer (score 0):

да, NetBeens является средой разработки на java